# storing File link in SDcard to SQLite Database

Tags: android

I have application that storing voice recording .3gp file in SDCard in particular folder for ex:- Recordings. I want to access that file path in database while clicking that path it should play the recordings ?. Any help would be greatly appreciable.
am using the function to find link of file

File directory = new File("sdcard/Recordings");

```
File file[] = directory.listFiles();  
            System.out.println("The length of files is " + file.length);
```

its not working

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need a `/` as first character of a path. `File directory = new File("/sdcard/Recordings");`

Comment: people, please stop saying "it is not working". Also, System.out won't help you in android. Use the Log class

Comment: am using system.out.println to check the path in logcat it will work in android logcat njzk2 and also thanks for zapl

Answer (score 0):

Here `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` Will make a path in your SDCard.

```
File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + getResources().getString(R.string.YourPath));
path.mkdirs();
```

Declare path in your Strings.xml

`<string name="YourPath">/Recordings/</string>`

Comment: .3gp file is storing in recordings folder in sdcard which is already exists. i want to access the file link to  database and play while clicking the link of file

Comment: @Nissar : For that you will have to get the path of it in path object. and pass it to intent for playing.

Comment: for getting path am using  File path = new File("/sdcard/Recordings") where file is currently storing it is not working and am not having any idea about how the .3gp file link will store in database while the recordinds are updating in the database while new recording occured.           sorry for messing arround the question and also thanks for your response

Comment: i mean to ask while recordings are updating in a  sdcard recordings folder that should be update in database. Thanks in advance